# Meteor server-side breakpoint never hit in cloud9

Tags: debugging, meteor, server-side, cloud9-ide

I can get a meteor app running in [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/) using built-in Meteor run config. But debugger doesn't hit any server-side break points. I also tried creating my own run config but doesn't work either:

```
{
  "cmd": [
    "bash",
    "--login",
    "-c",
    "meteor ${debug? run --debug-port=15454} --port $IP:$PORT"
  ],
  "debugger": "v8",
  "debugport": 15454,
  "info": "Your code is running at \\033[01;34m$url\\033[00m.\n\\033[01;31mImportant:\\033[00m use \\033[01;32mprocess.env.PORT\\033[00m as the port and \\033[01;32mprocess.env.IP\\033[00m as the host in your scripts!\n"
}
```

Anyone get the debugger working?

Comment: could you make it work??

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into the meteor debugging issue (I work for C9). I noticed there is a timing issue. It sometimes takes a long time (minutes) before meteor starts because it first starts databases and such. I changed the time the debugger waits before it gives up connecting to 10 minutes. Could it be that it is taking longer than 10 minutes for meteor to start?

Also note that c9 doesn't support client side code debugging. It only supports server side code.

Comment: Meteor takes longer to start than other Node apps of similar complexity (say 15s vs 5s) but I haven't seen latency >1min. What I found is if I add `debugger` statement to the code, it hits, but not the breakpoints I set in IDE. I also noticed the file it opens when hitting `debugger` is at `/app/server/...`, not my original file  `/simple-todos/server/...`. This seems like a clue, as if the file where I set breakpoint in IDE is not treated by debugger as source file.